# A box has 10 red balls and 5 black balls.

Tags: probability

Hey I am having trouble in solving this problem, I would really appreciate some help.

A box has 10 red balls and 5 black balls. A ball is selected from the box. If the ball is red, it is returned to the box. If the ball is black, it and 2 additional balls are added to the box. Find the probability that a second ball from the box is:
(a) Red
(b) Black

Obviously, the events are no longer independent. The main problem is how to set the first draw. I thought it may be solved using something like the defective machine production.

Comment: When the ball drawn is black, what color are the two additional balls?

Comment: I have seen this question in an homework, their the additional ball added were black.

Answer (score 0):

Can you find the probability if you know the first ball was black? how about red? Call the first one $b$ and the second $r$.

If you can, the total probability is $\frac{b}{3}+\frac{2r}{3}$