# Finding a probability function in this question (And solution verification).

Tags: probability, solution-verification, random-variables

Here's the question:

> In a bin there's $10$ black balls and $5$ red balls. We take out a random ball from the bin, if it's black, we return it to the bin, and if it's red we return it to the bin with another $2$ red balls. After that we take another ball that isn't returned to the bin.
>  
> a) Find the probability function of the number of red balls that are left in the bin. 
> b) What is the probability that the another ball we take is black? 
> c) Given that the another ball we took is red, what is the probability that the first ball we took was also red?

Note: I am still very new to random variables, and I think (a) is supposed to be solved using them, I even got confused of what to define in the start and still unsure of it. (I didn't solve (a), but I did (b) and (c) and put them here for solution verification, I'm interested to know if they should be solved after (a) and not like how I did). 
**My Work**: 
a) Let $X=$The number of red balls that are left in the bin. 
So I'm trying to find $P(X=k)$. I can see that $k$ can't be just anything, the minimum is when we take black ball first then red ball, we still have $4$ red balls, and the maximum is taking a red ball then a black ball, so we have $7$ red balls, so $4\le k\le 7$. 
Now what's my next step to work on finding a probability function? do I start to calculate $P(X=4)$ and $P(X=5)$ and... $P(X=7)$? so I will give it a try (I'm doing this randomly and I would appreciate feedback on whether this step is necessary or not). 
$P(X=4)=P(WeChooseBlackThenRed)=\frac {10}{15} \frac {5}{15}=\frac{2}{9}$
$P(X=5)=P(We ChooseTwoBlackBalls)=\frac{10}{15} \frac{10}{15}=\frac {4}{9}$
$P(X=7)=P(WeChooseRedThenBlack)=\frac{5}{15} \frac{10}{17}=\frac {10}{51}$ 
And I still couldn't find a way to generalize this into a function. 
**Solution Verification** 
b) Let $B_1$ be the event that we take a black ball in the first pull. 
and $B_2$ be the event that the second ball (another ball) is black. 
We want to know what is $P(B_2)$, so: 
$P(B_2)=P(B_2|B_1)P(B_1) + P(B_2|B_1^c)P(B_1^c)=\frac{10}{15} \frac{10}{15} + \frac{10}{17} \frac{5}{15} = \frac {98}{153}$ 

c) So we wanna know what is: $P(B_1^c |B_2^c)=?$. When we use Bayes theorem: 
$P(B_1^c | B_2^c)= \frac {P(B_2^c|B_1^c)P(B_1^c)}{P(B_2^c)}=\frac{\frac{7}{17} \frac{5}{15}}{\frac{7}{17} \frac{5}{15} + \frac{5}{15} \frac{10}{15}}=\frac{119}{275} $ 
Where I've done $P(B_2^c)=P(B_2^c|B_1^c)P(B_1^c) + P(B_2^c |B_1)P(B_1)$
Thanks in advance to any help and feedback it is all appreciated.

Comment: Don't know a *probability function* from a giraffe.  I agree with your math in all three parts.

Comment: You missed $X = 6$. Rest is all good. $P(X = 6) = \frac{1}{3} \cdot \frac{7}{17}$. That is you picked red both times.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1164072/a-box-has-10-red-balls-and-5-black-balls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And I still couldn't find a way to generalize this into a function.

It is a discrete random variable taking the values $\{4;5;6;7\}$ with the probabilities you correctly calculated.

$$X=\begin{cases}
\frac{102}{459},  & \text{if $x=4$} \\
\frac{204}{459},  & \text{if $x=5$} \\
\frac{63}{459},  & \text{if $x=6$} \\
\frac{90}{459},  & \text{if $x=7$} \\
0,  & \text{elsewhere} \\
\end{cases}$$

I prefer to express the probabilities with the same denominator so it is easier to verify that $X$ is a random variable...sum of the probabilities =1

Comment: Thanks for the answer, so basically it's not intended to be expressed as a function since it's discrete I can write it like this? is there any possible way to generalize it or I just missed the point that it's discrete with $4$ values so I can write it like that?

Comment: @Pwaol : what I wrote IS A FUNCTION. It is the probability mass function (pmf) of a discrete random variable; I only forgot to write "zero elsewhere" now I will amend it....You can also write down its CDF, which will result a "step function"....